# please help me to construct the reg ex in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, reactjs, string

The ask is to create a regular expression in JavaScript that holds true for the following format:- "APL-101"

1) Letters before '-' should be in caps, should not contain any special character and it can be any count.

2) After '-' the string should contain digits only, no special characters and alphabets required plus it can be of any count.

3) '-' will only be the special character that is allowed in the string and it should be mandatory

Need Your help.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried yet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one could help. try [it here](https://regex101.com/r/h3Hs5n/1/)

`[A-Z].*-[0-9].*`

Comment: Thanks a lot dear. It worked !